# JavaScript - repeat function that lists 'n' amount of random numbers within a range without duplicates

Tags: javascript, random, repeat, no-duplicates

I am trying to create an Animated Responsive Image Grid using [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedResponsiveImageGrid/).

In it's source code you can see that the code for those images are physically typed out individually rather than using a function that repeats it for a an 'n' amount of times. If you have a lot of pictures to list, that's painfully repetitive.

Therefore, I created this function:

```
function showImg() {
  for (var imgNum = 1; imgNum < 100; imgNum++) {
    document.write("<li><a href='#'><img src='img/" +imgNum+ ".jpg'/></a></li>");
  }
}

showImg();
```

This function is fine, however, every time the page is refreshed, it starts out with the same images in the same order. I don't want that. I want them to start with random images every time the page is refreshed. So I created a new code for that:

```
function showImg() {
  var imgNum = Math.floor((n+1)*Math.random());
  document.write("<li><a href='#'><img src='img/" +imgNum+ ".jpg'/></a></li>");
}

var n = 100;

for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
  showImg();
}
```

Great! Now, a new problem is that sometimes there will be duplicates. I don't want duplicates, not when the first set of images are loaded and not when the images begin to rotate/cycle through the animation. How do I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the numbers 1-100. Then "scramble" them: for 500 times, pick 2 of the array elements and swap their values. Finally, loop through that scrambled array, and show the image associated with the value of that array element.